# Spacemacsのsearch-engineレイヤーの検索エンジンの新規登録に関して

Tags: emacs, elisp, spacemacs

[spacemacs/layers/+web-services/search-engine/](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bweb-services/search-engine) を参考にして、`.spacemacs`における`dotspacemacs/layersのdotspacemacs-configuration-layers`に`search-engine`を追加し、`dotspacemacs/user-config`に

```
(push '(wikipedia-ja
        :name "ウィキペディア"
        :url "https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%s")
      search-engine-alist)
```

を追加しました
その後 `SPC q R (restart-emacs)` でSpacemacsを再起動して `SPC a / (search-engine-select)` から"ウィキペディア"を選択すると

> "Wrong type argument: commandp, engine/search-wikipedia-ja"

とエラーが出て日本語ウィキペディアでの検索ができません(他の検索エンジンは正常に動作しています)
現在使っている`.spacemacs`をリネームしSpacemacsを再起動してまっさらな`.spacemacs`に同様の操作を行っても結果は同じでした

ちなみに`HELM M-x (SPC SPC)`で engine/search で絞り込んだ結果には`engine/search-wikipedia-ja`は存在していませんでした

何が間違っているのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/.emacs.d/layers/+web-services/search-engine` ディレクトリの packages.el および funcs.el を編集すると Spacemacs のアップデートのときエラーが出てしまうので `~/.emacs.d/private/search-engine-revision` ディレクトリを作成しそこに新規で packages.el および funcs.el を作り，.spacemacs の `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` に `search-engine-revision` を追加しました．

- packages.el (投稿の都合上 URL は消去してありますが `~/.emacs.d/layers/+web-services/search-engine/packages.el` の URL と同じです)

  ```
  (defconst search-engine-revision-packages
    '((search-engine :excluded t))
  (setq search-engine-packages
        '(engine-mode)
        search-engine-alist
        '((amazon
           :name "Amazon"
           :url "")
          (bing
           :name "Bing"
           :url "")
          (duck-duck-go
           :name "Duck Duck Go"
           :url "")
          (google
           :name "Google"
           :url "")
          (google-images
           :name "Google Images"
           :url "")
          (github
           :name "Github"
           :url "")
          (google-maps
           :name "Google Maps"
           :url "")
          (twitter
           :name "Twitter"
           :url "")
          (project-gutenberg
           :name "Project Gutenberg"
           :url "")
          (youtube
           :name "YouTube"
           :url "")
          (stack-overflow
           :name "Stack Overflow"
           :url "")
          (spacemacs-issues
           :name "Spacemacs Issues"
           :url "")
          (spacemacs-pullrequests
           :name "Spacemacs Pull Requests"
           :url "")
          (wikipedia
           :name "Wikipedia"
           :url "")
          (wolfram-alpha
           :name "Wolfram Alpha"
           :url "")
          ))

  (defun search-engine/init-engine-mode ()
    (use-package engine-mode
      :commands (defengine spacemacs/search-engine-select)
      :defines search-engine-alist
      :init
      (progn
        (spacemacs/set-leader-keys
          "a/" 'spacemacs/search-engine-select)
        (dolist (engine search-engine-alist)
          (let ((func (intern (format "engine/search-%S" (car engine)))))
            (autoload func "engine-mode" nil 'interactive))))
      :config
      (progn
        (engine-mode t)
        (dolist (engine search-engine-alist)
          (let* ((cur-engine (car engine))
                 (engine-url (plist-get (cdr engine) :url)))
            (eval `(defengine ,cur-engine ,engine-url)))))))
  ```
- funcs.el

  ```
  (with-eval-after-load "helm"
    (defun spacemacs/helm-search-engine-select ()
      "Set search engine to use with helm."
      (interactive)
      (helm :sources (helm-build-sync-source "Search Engines Revision"
                        :candidates (mapcar (lambda (engine)
                                              (cons (plist-get (cdr engine) :name)
                                                    (intern (format "engine/search-%S"
                                                                    (car engine)))))
                                            search-engine-alist)
                        :action (lambda (candidate) (call-interactively candidate))
                        :migemo t))))

  (defun spacemacs/ivy-search-engine-select ()
    "Set search engine to use with ivy."
    (interactive)
    (ivy-read "Search Engines: "
              (mapcar (lambda (engine)
                        (cons (plist-get (cdr engine) :name)
                              (intern (format "engine/search-%S"
                                              (car engine)))))
                      search-engine-alist)
              :action (lambda (candidate) (call-interactively (cdr candidate)))))

  (defun spacemacs/search-engine-select ()
    "Set search engine to use."
    (interactive)
    (search-engine/init-engine-mode)
    (if (configuration-layer/layer-usedp 'ivy)
        (call-interactively 'spacemacs/ivy-search-engine-select)
      (call-interactively 'spacemacs/helm-search-engine-select)))
  ```

これで .spacemacs の `dotspacemacs/user-config` に以下のコードを追加すると日本語版スタック・オーバーフローと日本語版ウィキペディアも検索対象として helm で表示させ migemo を用いて絞り込めるようになります．

```
  (push '(stack-overflow-ja
          :name "スタック・オーバーフロー"
          :url "https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s")
        search-engine-alist)
  (push '(wikipedia-ja
          :name "ウィキペディア"
          :url "https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%s")
        search-engine-alist)
```